# Turn user string input into a vector

Tags: r, string, gsub

I m creating a script where user gives me some string seperated with comma. I need to automatically turn this :

```
words <- "hello, house, sun"
```

Into this:

```
words <- c("hello","house", "sun")
```

Do you have any idea on how to make it the right way?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `scan` to convert the string to a bunch of words

```
words1 <- trimws(scan(text = words, sep=",", what ="", quiet = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `strsplit`

```
words1 <- strsplit(words, ",\\s*")[[1]]
```